# Chrome for android lags down after many setInterval

Tags: jquery, gsap

I was trying this demo for one of my application but one of a touch screen TV is using android tablet 6.0.1 and it really lags after multiple clicks. Im suspecting due to the setinterval script there.

https://codepen.io/ShawnCG/pen/ZYVada

Here is the main javascript from that demo.

```
var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    sizes = [
      15, 20, 25, 35, 45
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],

    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount () {
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $d
    .one('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
      clearInterval( timer );
    })
    createParticle( event );
  }, 1000 / 60)

});


function createParticle ( event ) {
  var particle = $('<div class="particle"/>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((36 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;

  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();

  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;


    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + .25,
        transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
        webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });

    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
        particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 60);  
}
```

I have changed the jquery to gsap for the same animation. So instead of $(element).css(), im using Tweenlite.set()

Is there a way hardware speed up the browser for this sort of animation?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest performance hit is because you're using DOM elements. If you were to use `<canvas>` for your particles instead, it would perform *much* better (you could get hundreds or thousands of particles without much of a performance risk if you wanted to).

However, you can make this DOM animation *much* more performant than it is currently. The biggest thing to change is to use transforms instead of `top` and `left`. In GSAP you can do that by affecting the `x` and `y` properties. You should also use transform's `scale` instead of affecting `width`/`height`. In GSAP you should also set the `rotation` instead of the actual transform itself (it generates the property `transform` for you). I also recommend using GSAP's `.set()` method instead of jQuery's `.css()`. For even more performance, use GSAP's `.quickSetter()` method.

Using GSAP's `.delayedCall` instead of `setInterval` will also be more reliable. Even better, use `gsap.ticker()` and call all of the update functions from within that!

Altogether you get [this demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/povRaWB?editors=0010).

Other optimizations could be done, such as reusing the same particles and not creating/destroying the old ones, but the performance is about at its cap in terms of DOM animation. Like I said at the beginning, this sort of thing is perfect for `<canvas>`.

Comment: This has brought me to multiple trials and error but most importantly gave me a few fresh good perspective on performance with both gsap and canvas as im not very familiar with both. Thanks so so much for these ideas