# rapid clickings slows down the timer downdown on android chrome

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a mini game where user is required to click rapidly on a button in a given time (8 seconds). There is a countdown (to the mili seconds). While i was trying on an android touchscreen (using android table OS6 i think), i am experiencing the timer to slow down while rapidly clicking. Is there a way to avoid or improve the performance for this? This is the countdown timer which i assume could do an improvement? Not sure does GSAP helps to replace the setinterval in this matter?

```
function countDownNow(){
        // var initial = 800;
        var initial = 8000;
        var count = initial;
        var counter; //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

        function timer() {

            if (count <= 0) {
                console.log(done)

                clearInterval(counter);
                return;
            }
            count--;
            displayCount(count);
        }

        function displayCount(count) {
            var res = count / 100;
            //document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = res.toPrecision(count.toString().length) ;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
            ctx.font = '90px "Conv_DIN-Bold"';
            var text_title = "first";
            ctx.fillText(res.toPrecision(count.toString().length), 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);

        }
        counter = setInterval(timer, 10);


        displayCount(initial);   
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Skeleton html -->
<div id="countdown"></div>



<!-- this clickme button is the button where its being used for user to rapidly click it-->
<div class="clickme"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML code too? Also, I don't think you're supposed to define functions in a function.

Comment: @Yousername ahhh was that the reason why its quite slow? perhaps i can try taking them out n see the performance tonight? any other tips ? just am worried that too rapid clicking might hamper the app/browser whenever there is a very small interval going on at the same time

Comment: I'm not saying that's the reason, but maybe it could make the browser a bit faster.
Where does it detect for clicks? The problem may be in there. If the `setInterval` and the click detector are overlapping the clicks could stop the `setInterval`.

Comment: Also, maybe the problem is that clicks are different from tapping on the screen. When you click, your finger leaves the mouse, but when you tap, the "mouse position" is still on the button, which may leave the browser thinking that you are still clicking the button. I'm not sure how to fix this, but it might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [my answer to your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59395417/2065702), `setIntervals` should be avoided, especially when you have to use them for precise timing and *especially* when you're already using GSAP. There's no reason to use them if you're using GSAP.

For functionality like you have here there is no reason why it should ever perform poorly. The two biggest performance hits are 1) using a bunch of `setInterval`s and 2) having functions within functions.

When you have functions within functions they are created every time the function is ran. If those outer functions are called more than once, you are often times creating the inner functions more times than you need to. To avoid doing that, move the inner functions outside of the outer functions and use parameters to pass in variables if need be. (in terms of memory management, a minor improvement would be to move variables that don't change outside of the functions as well but that's much less important to do)

Another note is that the intervals that you are creating are all going to overwrite each other but you're not killing off the old ones. So you should kill off any that were created before since the output of them won't be seen (because it's covered by the new ones) anyway.

Altogether you get something like this: [**demo**](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/jOEwbgO?editors=0010).